# How long it takes to hear from a APS journal

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I have submitted my paper to a reputed APS journal. It has been 65 days, and I still did not get any response. Should I contact the editor regarding this? I have two papers published in this journal and last two times it only took around 45-50 days. However, I am in a dilemma, if I contact the editor will he get mad at me. Hoping to hear useful thoughts from you.

Comment: The difference between 45-50 days and 65 days is only two to three weeks. It's summer in the Northern Hemisphere. Many people take days off or in the slow mode. I would wait another two weeks before doing anything if I were you.

Comment: For PRC, PRD, the review time for me and my supervisor was about 2 months for a round (I also have 2 papers published with APS last year). So, I believe you can wait 2 3 weeks before contacting the editor.

Comment: @MikeyMike thanks. I think I should wait few more weeks then :)

Comment: @ user50724 I am curious what is the paper about if you don't mind.

Comment: @MikeyMike its about controlling energy transfer rate/optical switches based on quantum theories. And good news, I got the response and the paper got accepted with minor revisions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an author, I have had to wait anywhere from three days to seven months to get referee reports back from APS journals.  The time lapse is highly variable, although two months is a typical time.  I wouldn't even start to worry until it has been at least three or four months.  The APS editors are also generally pretty good about letting authors know if there has been an extended delay (most commonly caused, I understand, by a difficultly in finding willing referees).  If there's going to be a really long delay (over five or six months), they will probably send you an e-mail.

As a referee for the same journals, I can tell you that the editors like to hear back from referees within two weeks, but that doesn't necessarily mean the referee needs to submit a report within that time.  Often, a potential referee will take the whole two weeks just to let the editor know that they are not available.  And if they do promise a report, it may arrive another two to four weeks later.

In any case, if you are curious about the status of your article, you should consult APS's Author Status Inquiry System before contacting the editor.  The system (located at https://authors.aps.org/Submissions/status/ ) provides automated information about the workflow status of your paper.

Comment: thanks for your useful comment.  In my case, one referee has submitted the report in two weeks and other referee has not submitted it yet, which makes the delay in the process. Last two times editors waited only two months (or less than two months) for the delayed report and concluded that report will not be received. The decision was made based on one referee report. Anyway, I guess i should not be worried this soon then :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

The average length time in review differs between journals but also depends quite a bit on the reviewers themselves. I once had one held up 4 months due to one reviewer, who was ultimately replaced, which then took another 2 months, and that was just the first round.

It is totally acceptable to contact the action editor to ask for a status update, and I don't think he/she will get 'mad'. It's probably common and part of their role to field such questions.

Reviews do often get held up; this will also serve as a reminder to the action editor to make sure everything is proceeding as it should.

Comment: thanks. That's what exactly my supervisor says. I will wait few more weeks and contact the editor.

Comment: Thanks all I just received the response. It has taken around 70 days.

Comment: Unfortunately that's about average. Hopefully it's positive!

Comment: that's true. yeh its very positive :)